# Does wearing no footwear make you quieter?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG, being able to hear everything in your surroundings is obviously pretty important to every player, you want to get as much advantage over your opponents as possible.

So I've been told that wearing no boots/footwear can make your movement a little quieter, is this true and if so, how much? Are there any negative effects to not wearing any footwear?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wearing no footwear changes the sound of your footsteps. It does not make it any quieter.

There's no other disadvantages.

Answer (score 10):

Despite the fact that wearing no bootwear does not make the steps more quiet, the difference in the sound of steps can help you to distinguish the steps of your team from the steps of the opponent.

Answer (score 0):

look like true with this test but in game i dont feel any difference, the sound isn't the same but i dont hear louder or quieter.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean? The video you linked says that running barefoot IS quieter than running with shoes, except when on sand and wooden floors, when the opposite is true.